# Replicate hover effect in left sidebar

Tags: css, wordpress, menu, hover, sidebar

I am trying to replicate the hover effects in my left navigation menu to my right sidebar as well. Currently, I have got so the hover box only covers the text. I want the hover box to fully cover the link area like in the left menu.

Website: http://chemipharmaceutical.com/wp/

CSS for the right side bar links:

```css
#widget-link:hover, #widget-link.active {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #a00101;
  line-height: 1.5rem;
}
.widget a, .widget a:link {
    color: #fff;
    padding: 10px 20px;
}
```

Any input is appreciated. Thank you

Comment: could you share your html markup here? Also, in your three questions, you've linked to two completely different sites? (questions are raised when you've done something before and can't replicate it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)** your **#nav_menu-2** must have `padding:0;` (atleast for left and right)

**2)** your `<a>` in the menu must have `display: block;`

and that's it. Than you just have to play with margins and so one, to have identical spaces like in the left sidebar.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are looking for the hover effects to be on the parent div, instead of the child div you are looking for.

Below is an example of a navbar with some transitions like the one you are looking at, and note the structure of it.

```
    <li class="active">
      <a href="#">
        <span class="icon-home"></span>
        <span class="text">home</span>
      </a>
    </li>
```

You are more than likely wrapping your hover effect around the `<a>` attribute, instead of the `<li>` tag

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Try a navbar like [this example shows](http://jsfiddle.net/jbutler483/nxzvgbdL/)

It's even dynamic, as it collapses if the screen is resized.

```js
$('li').click(function() {

  $(this).addClass('active')
    .siblings()
    .removeClass('active');

});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #444;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 1em;
  text-align: center;
  color: #eee;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
.nav-container {
  width: 300px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 2px black;
  transition: all 0.3s linear;
}
.nav {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
li {
  height: 50px;
  position: relative;
  background: linear-gradient(#292929, #242424);
}
a {
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 50px;
  color: #bbb;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-left: 25%;
  border-left: 5px solid transparent;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  transition: all 0.3s linear;
}
.active a {
  color: #B93632;
  border-left: 5px solid #B93632;
  background-color: #1B1B1B;
  outline: 0;
}
li:not(.active):hover a {
  color: #eee;
  border-left: 5px solid #FCFCFC;
  background-color: #1B1B1B;
}
span[class ^="icon"] {
  position: absolute;
  left: 20px;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  transition: all 0.3s linear;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 860px) {
  .text {
    display: none;
  }
  .nav-container,
  a {
    width: 70px;
  }
  a:hover {
    width: 200px;
    z-index: 1;
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px 1px black;
  }
  a:hover .text {
    display: block;
    padding-left: 30%;
  }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .nav-container,
  a {
    width: 50px;
  }
  span[class ^="icon"] {
    left: 8px;
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>Slowly resize screen to see the width transition</h1>
<div class="nav-container">
  <ul class="nav">
    <li class="active">
      <a href="#">
        <span class="icon-home"></span>
        <span class="text">home</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <span class="icon-user"></span>
        <span class="text">about</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <span class="icon-headphones"></span>
        <span class="text">Audio</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <span class="icon-picture"></span>
        <span class="text">Portfolio</span> 
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <span class="icon-facetime-video"></span><span class="text">video</span>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Without seeing your markup here (i don't do external site links, apart from jsfiddle/codepen), then it's hard to advise any further